# Can't set xVar = range from worksheet.cells(numRow, yVarColumn)

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with proper syntax for setting variables as ranges...
Specifically, I'm testing a function I want to use in an app that creates new profiles and store the data, I will store that data on a hidden sheet, so they can be recalled at run time.
I'm currently construction a userform in order to create a new profile, the profile data needs to be stored to the first free column on the hidden sheet.
(where I will have to create a dynamic namedRange, so that i can use that range to save the associated data, and update the listbox in the userform)
Right now, I'm stumped by this:

```
Sub TestFindLastFunctions()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    'wb.activate 'shouldn't be neccesary
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = sh_02CRepStorage
    'ws.activate 'shoudn't be neccesary
       
    Dim trgtCol As Long
    trgtCol = LastColInSheet(ws) + 2
    Debug.Print trgtCol ' so far so good
    'Cells(1, trgtCol).Select 'another debug check - only works if sheet activated
    Dim trgtCell As Range
    Set trgtCell = ws.Cells(1, trgtCol) '<------- problem line
     
    Debug.Print trgtCell '<----- prints "" to the immediate window.
        
End Sub
```

The LastColInSheet function is copied form Ron de bruin's page: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm it simply returns a column number, in this case: 4.(One problem with it is if the sheet is empty, it returns an error, wondering if this can be fixed with an if statement in the function.)
I've tried many iterations of the problem line, some work but only if the storage sheet is activated, and give an error if not activate or selected, as the sheet will be hidden, I need this to work without activating the sheet, (although I could switch off screen activation?).
But I understand that it is best practice to avoid extraneous selects and activates, how can I just point directly to what I want and save that range into a variable?
It just doesn't seem like it should be so difficult, I must be missing something obvious.
It also seems like it shouldn't need so many lines of code to do something so simple.

Comment: You've got the right syntax. What's the error message?

Comment: Hi BigBen, I was getting the error message when trying other iterations of the problem line, sorry for the lack of clarity...
I think my problem was with the debug.print line... 
It needed to be `debug.Print trgtCell.Address`  ....with which it gives an absolute cell reference...

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is then (?)

Comment: I think I just answered it... but does that mean I have to use `trgtcell.address` 
when calling on the range? As in copying to it?

Comment: Also wondering I can do this a lot more efficiently...

Comment: No you don't need to use `Address` when copying to a range. You still haven't said *what* your problem is either, to be honest.

Comment: My problem was the way it was I was getting "" as output to the immediate window, of course, the cell was empty... What I wanted was the address....

Comment: But you're right, it was working perfectly... Outputting the value in the relevant cell.

Comment: Do you know that `trgtCol` computes to a reasonable value (and not zero)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried some more iterations of the "problem line" after some more searching...
-The real problem was with the debug.print line

```
Sub TestFindLastFunctions()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    'wb.activate 'shouldn't be neccesary
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = sh_02CRepStorage
    'ws.activate 'shoudn't be neccesary
       
    Dim trgtCol As Long
    trgtCol = LastColInSheet(ws) + 2
    Debug.Print trgtCol ' so far so good
    'Cells(1, trgtCol).Select 'debug Only works if already on sheet
      
    Dim trgtCell As Range
    'Set trgtCell = ws.Range _
    (ws.Cells(1, trgtCol), ws.Cells(1, trgtCol))
    ' unnecessarily complex, but correct if using .range?                                           
     'but works if insisting on range

     Set trgtCell = ws.Cells(1, trgtCol) 'back to original
     
    Debug.Print trgtCell.Address '<---problem was here?
End Sub
```